# New command: vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, macros

Right now I use `\\[0.5em]` to get vertical spacing.

But writing this every time is quite tiring, so I want to write a command that gives the same output simply by writing `\\` and wrote

```
\renewcommand{\\}{\\[0.5em]}
```

But it doesn't work. When using `\\` I get the same as before.

Comment: I would expect your redefinition to put text into an infinite loop, and no output, not give the previous results? you should almost never need to use `\\ ` outside of alignments, and almost never need `\\[..]` in alignments as the document defaults should be setting the required spacing. How come you need to do this often enough to require a command definition? (I was assuming that your redefinition was `\\ ` not `\\\\ ` it is unclear due to markup changes in the question.

Comment: I often use alignments, but I don't think the default spacing is enough so I always use `\\[0.5em]`. (Yes, I edited it)

Comment: It would be better to change the default spacing (`\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` for example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\renewcommand{\\}{\\[0.5em]}
```

if used would put TeX into an infinite loop however many latex environments redefine `\\` (`center`, `tabular`, `tabbing`, `flushright` all have different definitions of `\\`)  So within these environments your definition will be ignored. This makes globally redefining `\\` tricky (and ill-advised:-).

You could use

```
\newcommand\N{\\[.5em]}
```

and use `\N` if you want a definition, however you should almost never need
 `\\` outside of alignments, and within alignments you can usually arrange the default spacing so that you rarely need the optional argument.

Comment: Is it possible to change the default spacing of the align environment completely. As in before \begin{document} so I don't have to use \ arraystretch every time?

Comment: @Stranqer95 just define the length `\jot` to be bigger that controls the inter-line spacing in display math environments `\setlength\jot{10pt}` for example